# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString not return the right value

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

```
[wvPage stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
    @"function getDes(){var attrs = document.getElementsByClassName('description')[0];"
        "attrs = attrs.getElementsByClassName('table')[0]"
        "attrs = attrs.getElementsByTagName('li);"
        "var result='',i;"
        "for(i=0; i<attrs.length; i++)"
        "{"
        "  result += attrs[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML + ':' + attrs[i].getElementsByTagName('p')[1].innerHTML"
        "  if(i+1!=attrs.length)"
        "     result += '|'"
        "}"
    "return result;}"];

NSString* attribute_list = [wvPage stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getDes()"];
```

I use those line to get one string but nothing returned. What's wrong??

The target HTML is Here: http://d.pr/n/WT5a

Comment: Have you tried this out on your browser?

Comment: @nhahtdh yes, it worked in my safari ( which I change user agent to iPhone's agent)

Comment: Have you noticed that you're missing several semicolons (lines: 2, 7, 9) in your js string?

Comment: @Alladinian oh... I got it. Python's fault. Thank you.