# Lost the first line, stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString‘s strange thing

Tags: javascript, ios, dom, uiwebview

The stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString always lost the first line, what's wrong?

```
    NSString* attribute_list2 = [wvPage stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innerHTML;"]
```

[image]

As above, the result lost the

```
<html>
```

line.

I am doing any thing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML) of the element only contains the HTML fragment that describe the descendants of the node, so it will not contain the the element itself.

You may want to use [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.outerHTML) instead, which is the HTML fragment that includes the element itself and its descendants.

Comment: I got it. Can you solve this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537307/stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring-not-return-the-right-value#comment15253668_11537307